# Json4s: Decomposing to JValue gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using `Extraction.decompose` to produce a `JValue` and it is intermittently failing. I am asking it to decompose a `Seq` of the following case class:

```
case class Item(locators: Seq[String], dateAdded: DateTime = new DateTime(0L), newVersionSinceCuration: Option[Boolean] = None)
```

The `DateTime` is a `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

The same line of code will work the majority of times but every few minutes will fail with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:453)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2397)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2312)
    at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:2268)
    at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:1826)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:1119)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:966)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at org.json4s.DefaultFormats$$anon$4.format(Formats.scala:358)
    at org.json4s.ext.DateTimeSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$4$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(JodaTimeSerializers.scala:78)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.json4s.ext.InstantSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$3$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(JodaTimeSerializers.scala:57)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.json4s.ext.DurationSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$2$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(JodaTimeSerializers.scala:47)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.applyOrElse(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:146)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.addField$1(Extraction.scala:110)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeObject$1(Extraction.scala:140)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:228)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:189)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:64)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decompose(Extraction.scala:242)

    ...
```

So it seems to fail to parse the `DateTime`. I'm overriding the date format as per the Json4s documentation with the following:

```
implicit def json4sFormats = new DefaultFormats {
    override val dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
} ++ JodaTimeSerializers.all
```

I've googled around `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` problems with `sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate` and `SimpleDateFormat` and there's lots of posts about `SimpleDateFormat` not being thread safe. That seems like it could explain the error but I can see that [Json4s wraps the dateFormatter in a `ThreadLocal`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Formats.scala#L337), which I understand should make it thread safe.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

I am using Scala 2.11.8, Json4s 3.5.1, OpenJDK 1.8.0.

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defeating the `ThreadLocal` by making your `dateFormatter` a `val` instead of `def` as in the linked source for `DefaultFormats`, so all threads end up referring to the same instance. Of course, when you make it a `def`, `setTimeZone` needs to be done inside the definition.

Comment: That makes so much sense! I've made that change and so far I haven't seen any of those issues so I'm sure that's resolved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help Alexey!

Comment: @PaulL. You may want to accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark under it) in this case.

Comment: Sorry, long time listener first time caller.